# Different color on specific point on RGraph line chart

Tags: javascript, canvas, rgraph

I'm trying to specify a color in a point with `highlightStyle: 'halo',` and `tickmarksStyle: ['circle']` defined.

Graph:

[image]

I want to change the color of those points to red if they surpass that blue line. The condition is no big deal but can't seem to figure it out.

Or, if it's more simple, change the line segment color to red if the main line surpass the blue lines.

I'm been looking at the [Line chart API](https://www.rgraph.net/canvas/docs/line.html) but can't find a parameter that works with my scenario.

What can I do?

Comment: As of version 6.17 (to be released in 1-2 months from now (Feb 2024) you'll be able to easily accomplish this with the new clip: property which restricts drawing to only part of the canvas. More will (from when 6.17 is released) be available in the docs on the RGraph website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your request correctly then the easiest way would be to use the **filledThreshold** and **filledThresholdColors** properties.

Here's the code:

```
new RGraph.Line({
    id: 'cvs',
    data: [d1, d2],
    options: {
        backgroundGridHlinesCount: 5,
        backgroundGridVlines: false,
        backgroundGridBorder: false,
        axes: false,
        filled: true,
        filledRange: true,
        filledRangeThreshold: 12,
        filledRangeThresholdColors: ['red', 'blue'],
        xaxisLabels: ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P'],
        colors: ['transparent', 'transparent'],
        xaxisTickmarksCount: 15,
        tickmarksStyle: null
    }
}).draw();
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer Richard! On your example it works but on mine it throws a alert saying: "You must have only two sets of data for a filled range chart" and some weird chart: https://i.stack.imgur.com/57p1v.png

Comment: Do you want me to send on a Pastebin what I've done?

Comment: Well how many datasets do you have? Send me a link to your code.

Comment: So, instead of having a array with my datasets, I need to have multiple line objects?

Comment: That's right. Though any further datasets can be added to the second Line chart object if they use the same scale.

Comment: Thanks Richard, i'll try to replicate the example on my case and I'll give some feedback soon. I really like RGraph and also know you're the author of it so keep up the good work ;)